# Reference <form:select> value in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a page with `<form:select>` component and it's items a Map. How can I use selected value to send it to another controller with link below? The value I need named `${someValueINeed}`. Thanks

```
<form:form method="post" action="" commandName="user">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="division">
            Division
        </form:label>
            <form:select path="division">
                <form:option value="" label="-"/>
                <form:options items="${divisions}" />
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="id">
            User:
            </form:label>
            <form:select path="id">
               <form:options items="${users}" />
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" /></td>
    </tr>   
    </table>
    <a class="btn" href="<c:url value="/doctor/consultation/save/"/> ${form}/?userId=${someValueINeed}">Send request</a>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to send a form or call an action with an URL by a anchor?

I supposed that you would like to click this anchor ( tag) taking previous selected value.

You can concatenate it in jQuery:

```
<a id="link-action" class="btn" data-url="<c:url value="/doctor/consultation/save/"/>">Send request</a>
```

and append this js script (jQuery required):

```
<script>
  $("#link-action").click(function(){
    var $link = $(this);
    var $select = $("#select-id");
    self.window.location.href = $link.data("url") + "?userId=" + $select.val();
  });
</script>
```